# IBM Cloudant Capacity

Tags: database, cloudant

I am facing an issue with the IBM cloundant. I am using the 1GB free plan.
I have this dashboard showing me that I am using about 40mb from the plan, however, when I look my monitoring screen I see that my storage is using almost 700mb. What I can do to find where are all these huge data and delete them?

Below is the screenshot of my dashboard showing how much I am using in ALL my dbs

[image]

And here are my Monitoring screen saying that I am using much more
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the Cloudant dashboard. The numbers in the database list aren't reported correctly. I've raised this with the Cloudant development team. You can check the db data volume by a GET to the db name:

```
Stefans-MacBook-Pro:SAPI stefan$ acurl 'https://skruger.cloudant.com/aviation' | jq .
{
  "update_seq": "68396-[stuff]wo4M",
  "db_name": "aviation",
  "purge_seq": 0,
  "sizes": {
      "file": 88201146,
      "external": 88457573,
      "active": 60042977
  },
```

What you are looking for is the `sizes.external` value.

EDIT Jun 24, 2021 -- a dashboard fix for this was deployed today.